# How to pass credentials securely in a http url?

Tags: security

I have a public facing web page in .Net that I would like to put anchor tags in that go to a web page produced by a Java server in my distributed system.  For example, Bob logs in from the WWW and goes to the home page.  I would like to have a link to http://javaserver/form.jsp?username:Bob in the home page.  But that would be insecure if someone on the internal network was snooping.  They could just put in that url and act as Bob through a replay attack.  Encoding the username is also open to a replay attack.  Any ideas?
Thanks!

**https**://javaserver/form.jsp?username:Bob still opens me to a replay attack by just putting in that url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `https` on the public and the private servers
- Send the user id and add a long and random token that will validate the user (to be delegated to the original server if necessary).
- Use POST requests if you can

The random token should be created with a cryptographically secure random number generator. It should also be changed/invalidated after a certain amount of time. If you are going to delegate the verification to the public server, you will also need to authenticate the delegating (local) server in a secure manner. To prevent brute-force attacks, block repeated invalid attempts.

There are quite a few pitfalls, so be wary of implementing any sort of security mechanism yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use cookies and SSL in your authentication. I'd be surprised if you aren't already.

Comment: I started thinking the same thing, but it wouldn't work if he is passing to a new domain, right?

Comment: @Joel: it wouldn't work with all domains, but in that case, you need more than this simple mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm - just thinking out loud - if its not https, its open to snooping.  You could encrypt the username with a timestamp so that the window is brief.  not a great answer, but since http is not secure....

Answer (score -2):

I think the best solution is to use https. This way anything you send to Bob is secure from prying eyes.